# After changing all font-family, font awesome icons show up as squares

Tags: font-awesome

After applying the below codes, the font awesome icons show up as squares. If I apply it to `body` tag. It doens't overwrite all font-family, so I had to apply it to `*`. How can I fix this error?

```
<style>
  * {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif !important;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because font awesome requires the FontAwesome `font-family` to be applied to icon elements, in order to source and render the icons correctly.

Your styles are likely overwriting this FontAwesome behaviour.

One way to fix this would be to ensure font awesome's `.fas` class still correctly applies the required FontAwesome font to `.fas` elements. You could do this by updating your CSS:

```
<style>
  * {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  }

  .fas { 
    font-family:FontAwesome; 
  }
</style>
```

Or, if your browser supports the `:not` CSS3 selector:

```
<style>
  *:not(.fas) {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Helped a lot! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Font Awesome 5 You can use this

```css
.fab
{
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands' !important;
}

.fas, .far, .fa
{
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free' !important;
}
```